# c50 runs for +1 hour, then returns c50 code called exit with value 1

Tags: r

I looked at other questions regarding my error but none had a similar issue as I do. I have no empty values, and none of the variable names in the dataset are used by the C50 package.

This is the structure of the used dataset (no empty values):

```
> str(dataset)
'data.frame':   776973 obs. of  13 variables:
$ CrimeID            : int  9446748 9446846 9446876 9447044 9447227 9447263 9447282 9447312 9447340 9447387 ...
$ CaseNumber         : Factor w/ 776907 levels "161884","F218264",..: 67 111 157 283 372 404 421 435 457 487 ...
$ CrimeDate          : Factor w/ 326056 levels "1/1/2014 0:00",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ CrimeBlock         : Factor w/ 31381 levels "0000X E 100TH PL",..: 3101 4085 26441 10811 6414 3183 7076 11201 12166 5271 ...
$ IUCR               : Factor w/ 357 levels "031A","031B",..: 345 51 52 333 52 347 347 345 52 334 ...
$ LocationDescription: Factor w/ 135 levels "ABANDONED BUILDING",..: 24 18 122 24 122 122 122 18 122 122 ...
$ Arrest             : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
$ Domestic           : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
$ Beat               : int  1832 1133 1631 1932 1932 1533 1012 1413 1033 1211 ...
$ District           : int  18 11 16 19 19 15 10 14 10 12 ...
$ Ward               : int  42 24 36 43 32 24 24 35 12 26 ...
$ CommunityArea      : int  8 27 17 7 7 25 29 22 30 24 ...
$ FBICode            : Factor w/ 26 levels "01A","01B","04A",..: 24 11 11 24 11 25 25 24 11 24 ...
```

The variable Arrest will be used as target variable in the decision tree process. I thus factorize the variable, rename the dataset as crimechicago, set the seed to create random training and test datasets, load librar c50, and run the c50 code. This code runs for over an hour and then returns the error:  c50 code called exit with value 1

```
dataset$Arrest<- factor(dataset$Arrest)
crimechicago <- dataset
set.seed(222) 
totalvalues <-nrow(crimechicago)
train_sample <- sample(totalvalues, 400000) 
crimechicago_train <- crimechicago[train_sample, ] 
crimechicago_test  <- crimechicago[-train_sample, ] 
library(C50)
crimechicago_model <- C5.0(crimechicago_train[-7], crimechicago_train$Arrest)
```

EDIT:

-removed CrimeID and CaseNumber from dataset as not useful predictors of target variable Arrest

-summary screenshot of the dataset: (the entire dataset, not a subset)

[image]

structure of the train dataset (400,000 rows, created by randomly selecting 400,000 rows of the 700,000+ row original dataset)

```
str(crimechicago_train)
'data.frame':   400000 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ CrimeDate          : Factor w/ 326056 levels "1/1/2014 0:00",..: 300760 132223 211541 3 287239 54284 93432 133588 284191 232747 ...
 $ CrimeBlock         : Factor w/ 31381 levels "0000X E 100TH PL",..: 124 14942 2696 24466 143 9024 10613 22404 17613 10766 ...
 $ IUCR               : Factor w/ 357 levels "031A","031B",..: 209 274 25 51 334 345 329 274 347 329 ...
 $ LocationDescription: Factor w/ 135 levels "ABANDONED BUILDING",..: 118 18 80 106 80 110 18 118 122 18 ...
 $ Arrest             : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Domestic           : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ Beat               : int  113 1133 1834 825 1834 1434 1921 715 2522 1431 ...
 $ District           : int  1 11 18 8 18 14 19 7 25 14 ...
 $ Ward               : int  42 24 42 15 42 32 47 15 30 1 ...
 $ CommunityArea      : int  32 27 8 66 8 24 5 67 20 22 ...
```

Comment: That's a *lot* of data - have you tried it for subsets, like 1/100th of the data?

Comment: @Spacedman, I haven't yet. Could the size of the dataset be the reason why I get that error? I understand it could be why the code runs for a long time, but I'm not sure if creating subsets of the data would avoid the error code.

Comment: If its not the reason for the error, you might get the error quicker which will make it much quicker to find the real error. And if the error is due to a particular row then the error might disappear, then maybe you can try more subsets until you find it. For now all we can give you is generic investigative debugging advice.

Comment: Are you putting the CrimeID in as a predictor? Because that's a unique ID for each item, so probably has no value in a predictive model. Ditto CaseNumber. I don't know if that will mess up the function to the extent of producing that error but it makes me think you should think about your model a bit more.

Comment: I reduced the dataset to 10,000 rows and still got that error. And yes, all other variables are used as predictor, thank you for noticing that mistake regarding crimeID. I just learned about the concept of decision trees and am still learning.

Comment: Keep chopping it down! I suspect its something structural in the data. Once you get to 500 rows you can probably share a conveniently-sized file for us to replicate your problem. You could also add the output of `summary` on your data to the question...

Comment: Giving us the `str(crimechicago_train)` might be helpful too to ensure that the factor conversion worked okay. I would also suggest specifying the model with a formula, e.g. `C5.0(Arrest ~ ., data = crimechicago_train)`, it will allow you to add specific variables one at a time (replacing the . with a formula) to pinpoint which predictor(s) is causing the issue.

Comment: @Spacedman, I'm currently playing around with the size of the dataset. I added a summary of the entire dataset as per your suggestion. And vincentmajor, I added the structure of the crimechicago_train dataset and it appears the arrest variable is converted to a factor correctly. I will try to specify the model with a formula.